# Mercurial keeps starting FileMerge instead of kdiff3

Tags: macos, mercurial

I want to merge some stuff in mercurial using kdiff3. Therefore I installed kdiff3 and added the following to `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
```

But Mercurial keeps calling FileMerge as merge tool. I first checked if kdiff3 is working at all. Calling it from spotlight opened it. Then I called it from the command line to check whether HG is not able to call it, but this also worked. Then I found somewhere the hint to pass the complete path in the `.hgrc`:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

But this also didn't help. There is also no error message from kdiff3 when Mercurial wants to open the merge tool, only some strange errors from FileMerge.

Question is: Why is Mercurial refusing to open kdiff3?

Comment: Becoz u wanna [RTFM](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui), dude

Comment: @LazyBadger Thanks for this polite and helpful comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the endless efforts of one of the most polite user here on stack exchange, I finally figured out that the mercurial wiki seems to be outdated. [There](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3) it says:

> Add to ~/.hgrc:
>
> ```
> [extensions] 
> hgext.extdiff =
>
> [extdiff]
> cmd.kdiff3 =
>
> [merge-tools]
> kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
> ```

The extdiff extension is not needed, as I don't want to define a new `hg kdiff3` command here.

But Mercurial has some more settings for the merge tool:

```
[ui]
merge = kdiff3
```

Regarding to the [Mercurial help on merge tools](https://selenic.com/hg/help/merge-tools), the `ui.merge` setting should not be necessary, as I specifically set a merge-tools configuration:

> Mercurial uses these rules when deciding which merge tool to use:
>
> 1. If a tool has been specified with the --tool option to merge or resolve, it is used. If it is the name of a tool in the merge-tools
>      configuration, its configuration is used. Otherwise the specified tool
>      must be executable by the shell.
> 2. If the "HGMERGE" environment variable is present, its value is used and must be executable by the shell.
> 3. If the filename of the file to be merged matches any of the patterns in the merge-patterns configuration section, the first usable
>      merge tool corresponding to a matching pattern is used. Here, binary
>      capabilities of the merge tool are not considered.
> 4. If ui.merge is set it will be considered next. If the value is not the name of a configured tool, the specified value is used and must be
>      executable by the shell. Otherwise the named tool is used if it is
>      usable.
> 5. If any usable merge tools are present in the merge-tools configuration section, the one with the highest priority is used.
> 6. If a program named "hgmerge" can be found on the system, it is used - but it will by default not be used for symlinks and binary
>      files.
> 7. If the file to be merged is not binary and is not a symlink, then internal ":merge" is used.
> 8. The merge of the file fails and must be resolved before commit.

I somehow have the feeling that Mercurial changed it's behavior here (or some other part of my system), because on all machines where I used kdiff3 I don't have the last setting in my .hgrc. However, adding `ui.merge` does the trick.